# How do I fix my out of bounds error?

Tags: java, excel, file, csv, indexoutofboundsexception

Up until now, my program has been working fine. For some reason despite having not changed anything to do with the code below, I am recieveing an out of bounds error. So basically my program is reading data from an excel sheet and putting this data into a combo box. For example the excel sheet data is something like this: firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber etc. When I run my code, "data[0]" is accepted, however anything beyond this apparently out of bounds. Despite the fact that it tells me it is out of bounds, it still reads the data and does what it should, why am I getting this error?

```
try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Clients.csv"));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                String line = "";
                String cvsSplitBy = ",";
                String fullName = null;

                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Clients.csv"));
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                        fullName = data[0]+" "+data[1];
                        comboBox_1.addItem(fullName);
                    }
                    br.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Remove the `Try-Catch` and check on which line do you get the error.

Comment: `fullName = data[0]+" "+data[1];` => what makes you think that data has two elements?

Comment: So this would probably be a good fix - `fullName = data[0];` Can you try it?

Comment: @Vityata `fullName = StringUtils.join(data, ' ');` is a safer bet

Comment: Did you check the *cvsSpliBy* string is representing the real separator in the failing case? A proper reason for getting only a single array element woul be that the current *line* does not contain the seperator.

Comment: @assylias it has 7 elements. I gave an example above of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only line that can throw exception is `fullName = data[0] + " " + data[1]`. May be your `line` variable has no split symbol. So `data` array has only 1 element. Try following:

```
String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
fullName = data[0];
if(data.length > 1) {
    fullName += " " + data[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the error I was having!